# How to create the best veg noodles?

Tags: vegetarian, chinese-cuisine, noodles

I am newbie to cooking,
I will have to create veg noodles , I am following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27oHn30Az4E) tutorial,

I want to know what are the add-ons I can add it to make it testy and best.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main sources of flavour in any Chinese-style noodle dish will be:

- Garlic
- Ginger
- Chilli
- Spring Onion/Scallion
- Soy sauce
- Oyster sauce
- Rice wine / dry sherry
- Sesame oil

Sesame oil has a very distinctive 'Chinese' flavour. It is very strong so you only need a little. You should not use it for frying - think of it more like a seasoning. Add a teaspoon or so at the end of cooking and stir through.

Comment: Any addition/correction if I want to serve it with [Thai Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_curry) ?

Comment: Fish sauce (nam pla), lime juice, and fresh coriander leaves. You want to keep it fairly simple so as not to clash with the curry itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serve your noodles with Thai Curry, I think you can use what @ElendilTheTall suggested plus serving with bean sprouts and maybe some mint and basil. I may also consider adding some fish sauce / lime and crushed peanuts. This is more toward to the thai flavour.

My recipe would have the following

1. Garlic
2. Ginger
3. Chilli
4. Shallot/spring onion
5. Soy sauce
6. Sesame oil
7. Fish sauce / lime
8. crushed peanuts
9. bean sprouts
10. mint / basil

Also, the type of noodles is important too. Since you will have it with Curry, I would suggest the thick white/egg noodles. The thicker noodles will absorb the curry better.

If you want to use rice noodles, maybe you can skip most of the ingredients above and just pour curry over the noodles with some bean sprouts and a bit of herbs. In that case, you can taste the true flavour of curry.

Good Luck